# Common Component logic solved by Composition instead of inheritance in React-Native

Tags: react-native, inheritance, composition, redux-saga

We're developing a react-native app with redux-saga.

The moment you look for inheritance in react, you always find: *don't do it, use composition!* with examples how to re-use layout with composition.

The problem now is that this is not about layout, but about common constructor logic. I'll give you the specific case:

- LoggedOutComponent
- LoggedInComponent

If a user navigates to a Component extending the LoggedOutComponent, the first common step is to check whether the user is logged in. If he is, we navigate to the home screen of the LoggedIn-part and vica versa for the LoggedInComponent.

Is there a better way to achieve this without using inheritance. Or is this a good example where inheritance is the way to go? I don't want to write the same logic in every component.

Comment: I have the same requirement and am running into the same challenges.  I do see where composition is useful, but it seems to me like sometimes inheritance is the way to go.  And your use case seems like just such a case to me.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me like the wrong way to go if you're trying to navigate from within the constructor of components.
can you elaborate more on what exactly you're tying to achieve?

Comment: Exactly what I said. There are about 10 components which are in the not-logged-in part. If you for some reason enter a non-logged-in page, while being logged in, you need to get redirected to the logged-in part

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure I understood you, but the way I see it, you have two options:

1. Write a "navigateLoggedIn(route)" method, in which you will check whether the user is logged in or not. if he's NOT logged-in, this method will navigate to the login screen route. if he is logged in, this method will navigate to the given route param.
   make sure that if you have a log-out flow somewhere in the app, to navigate to the login screen route at the end of this flow.
2. the second option would be to create a wrapper component class called for example ForceLoggedIn. this class would check in its render method whether the user is logged in. if he is, show the contents of this.props.children, otherwise, show the contents of the login page
   You can then use this wrapper component in your code with: